# How to pretty print JSON inside sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

I'm trying to pretty print a JSON variable inside sapui5 form. I have this below code:

```
var dataActualMeasure, oModelActualMeasure;

function initActualMeasure() {
    dataActualMeasure = {
        status: ""
    }
    oModelActualMeasure = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
    oModelActualMeasure.setData(dataActualMeasure);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModelActualMeasure, "actualMeasure");
};
initActualMeasure();

function updateMeasures() {
    oModelActualMeasure.loadData(url + "/?action=Status");
    oModelActualMeasure.attachRequestCompleted(
        function() {
            oModelActualMeasure.refresh();
        });
}

var measuresForm = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm(
    "measuresForm", {
        maxContainerCols: 1,
        editable: true,
        content: [
            new sap.ui.core.Title({
                text: "Kafka Status"
            }),
            new sap.m.Label({
                text: "Status"
            }),
            new sap.m.Input({
                value: "{actualMeasure>/status}"
            }).setEditable(false)
        ]
    });

var page = new sap.m.Page("page", {
    title: "Results",
    content: [
        measuresForm
    ]
});
```

The window is refreshed every 1 second, so a new jSON value will be assigned to the variable 'status' every second which is getting printed in the page but not pretty printed. How shall I pretty print it.
I tried declaring

```
var jsonString =  JSON.stringify(oModelActualMeasure.getData().status);
```

and include this variable  in the page content[], but this is not helping me. Please help me. I'm beginner in sapui5.

Comment: What control are you using to pretty-print the JSON string? An `sap.m.Input` or `sap.m.Label` are just single-line controls...

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify` [parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```
//JSON.stringify(value[,replacer[, space]])
var jsonString =  JSON.stringify(oModelActualMeasure.getData().status, null, '\t');
```

**space** will do the following (from developer.mozilla.org):

*A String or Number object that's used to insert white space into the output JSON string for readability purposes. If this is a Number, it indicates the number of space characters to use as white space; this number is capped at 10 if it's larger than that. Values less than 1 indicate that no space should be used. If this is a String, the string (or the first 10 characters of the string, if it's longer than that) is used as white space. If this parameter is not provided (or is null), no white space is used.*

Comment: I have deleted the measuresForm  variable, and I placed the above jsonString variable inside page content like:

content : [
                        new sap.m.Label({text:"Status"}), jsonString
                    ]
Now the sapui5 page is not even loading. You have any suggestions...